# Project Euler #23 in C# inefficient code execution time

Tags: c#, performance

I have gone through my code and tried to make it as efficient as i can think possible. Still i can not get this program to run all the way through without freezing my box. The maximum amount of time that i have let it run without it freezing it was about 2 hours. I can not believe this did not execute in that amount of time.

Is it an issue with my computer or is this brute force method of solving this problem that inefficient.

What are some ways that i can avoid this type of inefficiency when writing methods in the future?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList listOfAbundantNumbers = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listOfSums = new ArrayList();
        long total = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 20162; i++)
        {
            if (isAbundandt(i))
            {
                listOfAbundantNumbers.Add(i);
            }
            total+=i;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; a++)
            {
                long temp1 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[i]);
                long temp2 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[a]);
                long num = temp1 + temp2;
                if(listOfSums.Contains(num) == false)
                {
                    listOfSums.Add(num);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
        {
            long temp1 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[i]);
            total -= temp1;
        }

        printLn(total + "");
    }

    private ArrayList divisorList(long input)
    {
        ArrayList divisors = new ArrayList();
        for (long i = 2; i < Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(input),0,0); i++)
        {
            long temp = input % i;
            if (temp == 0)
            {
                divisors.Add(i);
                divisors.Add(input / i);
            }
        }
        return divisors;
    }

    private Boolean isAbundandt(long input)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        ArrayList divisor = divisorList(input);

        for (int i = 0; i < divisor.Count; i++)
        {
            long temp1 = Convert.ToInt64(divisor[i]);
            sum += temp1;
        }
        sum++;

        if (sum > input)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Simple nested loops over 1..n have O(n^2) complexity .. this can be even worse because of other implicit loops. (That is, a different algorithm should be explored.)

Comment: It's common for Euler problems to intentionally be impossible to solve by brute force methods. You have to rethink the solution. To figure out how to do that for yourself is the entire point of the Euler problems.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any infinite loops in there, but it's quite an expensive operation you are running.  I would try running it with something lower than 20162 (like 50 or something) just to make sure the calculations work in the first place.  It could just be the number of loops you are doing just takes a long time.

Comment: So it doesnt have anything to with any of the classes i am using (arraylist) or the fact that i am using their built in methods for contains and i am converting to longs?

For some reason as well im not getting the correct abundant numbers. 
Looking inside my listofabundantnumbers leads me to seeing these numbers "18,24,30,36,40,48,54" which are all abundant but im missing some. I thought of a way to possibly speed up the nested for loops but the solution i came up with is another nested for loop if i remember correctly.

Comment: What's the purpose of listOfSums by the way? You put values in there after a costly Contains check in a double nested loop, but don't do anything with it.

Comment: Oh wow thanks Pierre, looks like my code has not gotten far enough to notify me of that issue. Looks like when typing my ide prefilled that as the wrong list and i didnt catch it. It should be used down below, i will fix that in the question now.

Comment: Learn how to measure what parts of your code are fast and what parts are slow;  you can start by simply using the `Stopwatch` class to time your loops. Once you've identifies which loop is slow, then identify which statement in the loop is taking most of the time. Then figure out how to use a data structure that makes that statement faster.

Comment: If you are not even getting the correct results then *fix that first*, obviously. There's no point in trying to make a wrong program faster.

Comment: I noticed that after i posted the results, i thought it was outputting the correct values before. And i was aware it was the nested for loop that was being dreadfully slow, i just did not know if it was because of all the conversions and everything else that was going on or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `ArrayList`, prefer generic collection such as `List<Int64>` because you conversion may be quite expensive.

There is a part in your program which is in *O(n^3)*. It can be reduce to *O(n^2)* easily. Just replace the following code (*O(n)* because of `List<T>.Contains`):

```
if(listOfSums.Contains(num) == false)
{
    listOfSums.Add(num);
}
```

by:

```
listOfSums.Add(num);
```

where `listOfSums` is now a `HashSet<Int64>` (it's used to have a collection without duplicates).

Moreover, you can reduce the time for populating the `listOfSums` by a factor of 2 by just noticing that if you exchange `i` and `a`, the `sum` is the same, then, only one of the two combinations is added to the `listOfSums`.

You can replace:

```
for (int i = 1; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
    for (int a = 0; a < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; a++)
```

by;

```
for (int i = 1; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
    for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
```

The final code is:

```
private static void Main()
{
    List<Int64> listOfAbundantNumbers = new List<Int64>();
    HashSet<Int64> listOfSums = new HashSet<Int64>();
    long total = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 20162; i++)
    {
        if (isAbundandt(i))
        {
            listOfAbundantNumbers.Add(i);
        }
        total += i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
        for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++)
        {
            long temp1 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[i]);
            long temp2 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[a]);
            long num = temp1 + temp2;
            listOfSums.Add(num);
        }

    for (int i = 1; i < listOfAbundantNumbers.Count; i++)
    {
        long temp1 = Convert.ToInt64(listOfAbundantNumbers[i]);
        total -= temp1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(total + "");
}

private static List<Int64> divisorList(long input)
{
    List<Int64> divisors = new List<Int64>();
    for (long i = 2; i < Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(input), 0, 0); i++)
    {
        long temp = input % i;
        if (temp == 0)
        {
            divisors.Add(i);
            divisors.Add(input / i);
        }
    }
    return divisors;
}

private static Boolean isAbundandt(long input)
{
    long sum = 0;
    List<Int64> divisor = divisorList(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < divisor.Count; i++)
    {
        long temp1 = divisor[i];
        sum += temp1;
    }
    sum++;

    if (sum > input)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Euler problems are meant for learning, I would not just give the exact solution for it.  A nudge in the right general direction is usually enough.

Comment: @JBetter Should I remove my answer?

Comment: I am not opposed to him leaving the code but others may be. I want to learn more efficient ways to handle what i was doing and wanted to know the downfall of different classes and that's exactly the information your giving me.

Besides the code still has a few logical errors in it that havent entirely been pointed out. Someone that was wanting to just copy and paste would be sorely disappointed with the wrong answer.

Comment: @CédricBignon Your use of generic lists is exactly what i needed. I did not copy and paste your code but did use the generics you suggested and now the program runs in about 3 seconds. Unfortunately it is not ouputting the correct answer but thats a logic issue that i can solve myself.

Comment: @AaronSiciliano Good! Do you use HashSet<T> too?

Comment: @CédricBignon Yes i used the exact recommendations for classes that you recommended. They are immensely faster, and while your nor my code actually produces the project 23 answer, you did interpret my questions correctly and answer the questions that i actually wanted answered. If i could give you positive rep i would haha.